# How can I get a list of tables connected to each module in AX 09?

Tags: axapta, x++

Can anyone tell me how to find the list of tables that are connected to each module in AX 09?

I would really appreciate any insight on how to do this.

Kindly Help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can get a list of tables related to specific configuration keys by running following job:

```
static void FindTablesFromConfigKey(Args _args)
{
    // The name of the configuration key to be specified here
    str                     configKeyName   = "Prod";
    Dictionary              dictionary      = new Dictionary();
    ConfigurationKeyId      configKeyId     = dictionary.configurationKeyName2Id(configKeyName);
    TableId                 tableId;
    DictConfigurationKey    dictConfigurationKey;
    DictTable               dictTable;
    container               keyIds;
    int                     i;
    ;

    if (configKeyId)
    {
        // Find all children of the specified configuration key
        for (i = dictionary.configurationKeyNext(0); i; i = dictionary.configurationKeyNext(i))
        {
            dictConfigurationKey = new DictConfigurationKey(i);

            while (dictConfigurationKey.parentConfigurationKeyId())
                dictConfigurationKey = new DictConfigurationKey(dictConfigurationKey.parentConfigurationKeyId());

            if (dictConfigurationKey.id() == configKeyId)
                keyIds += i;
        }

        // Find all tables that have an appropriate configuration key
        i = 0;
        for (tableId = dictionary.tableNext(0);tableId;tableId = dictionary.tableNext(tableId))
        {
            dictTable = new DictTable(tableId);
            if (!dictTable.isMap() && !dictTable.isTmp() && !dictTable.isView())
            {
                if (confind(keyIds, dictTable.configurationKeyId()))
                {
                    i++;
                    info(dictTable.name());
                }
            }
        }
    }

    info(strfmt("%1 tables have configuration key '%2'", i, configKeyName));
}
```

You can use following configuration keys in the job:
**LedgerBasic** : General ledger
**Bank** : Bank
**SysAdmin** : Administration
**LogisticsAdvanced** : Logistics
**LogisticsBasic** : Trade
**ProjBasic** : Project
**QuotationBasic** : Quotations
**AIF** : Application Integration Framework
**Currency** : Currency
**ReportingServices** : Reporting Services
**COSBaseModule** : Cost accounting
**Asset** : Fixed assets
**PBA_ProductBuilder** : Product Builder
**Req** : Master planning
**smmOutlook** : Microsoft Office Outlook synchronisation
**LedgerAdvanced** : General ledger - advanced
**Prod** : Production Series I
**WrkCtr** : Resources
**ProdRouting** : Production Series II
**SysDevelopmentXPP** : X++ development
**ProdShop** : Production Series III
**SMAManagement** : Service management
**SmmCRM** : CRM Series
**Event** : Event
**TradeAgreements** : Trade agreements
**AIFWebService** : Application Integration Framework Web Services
**Trv** : Expense management
**TradeInterCompany** : Intercompany
**SysDevelopmentMorphX** : Development
**ProjAdvanced** : Project - advanced
**WMSBasic** : Warehouse Management I
**WMSAdvanced** : Warehouse Management II
**KMBSC** : Balanced Scorecard
**EP** : Enterprise Portal
**HRMAdministration** : Human Resource I
**RFID** : RFID
**SysDatabaseLog** : Database log
**CSS** : Customer Self-Service
**SmmSM** : Sales management
**BankElectronicBanking** : Electronic Banking
**ESS** : Employee Self-Service
**BAS** : Business analysis
**PurchReq** : Purchase Requisition
**InventQualityManagement** : Quality management
**COSPlanCostCalc** : Flexible Budgeting
**SMASubscription** : Subscription
**JmgPayroll** : Shop Floor Control - Pay generation
**HRMCollaborative** : Human Resource III
**CRSECountry** : Country/Regional specific features
**JmgJob** : Shop Floor Control - Job registration
**SIG** : Electronic signature
**LedgerAdvanced2** : General ledger - advanced II
**HRMManagement** : Human Resource II
**KMBPM** : Business Process Management
**KMQuestionnaireBasic** : Questionnaire I
**Jmg** : Shop Floor Control
**SmmTM** : Telemarketing
**SmmMA** : Marketing automation
**KMQuestionnaireAdvanced** : Questionnaire II

Answer (score 1):

Check this link for the ExtractTablesNamesFromConfigs class which is improvised and automates the process of exporting the tables to multiple text files as per the configuration keys. There are around 207 keys and details provided here   http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/320272/Extract-All-tables-from-Dynamics-AX-Data-Dictionar